# How do I do something to each element in a list?

Tags: python

I am currently making a bingo game that calls a number when enter is pressed. It does this until the player's bingo card is empty.

I can not get it so that it calls the first number in the list of numbers and goes on to the second then the third and so on without making a script for each of the 99 numbers.

What I want to do is get the program to find the first element of `nums` and then get the program to print the string and if the string is in the `player_1` list then remove the string from `player_1` and keep on doing the process until either the program has gone through all the strings or the `player_1` list has no strings left in the list.

Here is my code:

```
import random

def player_1_card():
   print(player_1[1:4])
   print(player_1[5:8])
   print(player_1[9:12])
   print(player_1[13:16])
return

nums = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99']

random.shuffle(nums)
player_1 = random.sample((nums), 16)

while len(player_1) != 0:
        input("Press <enter> to call a number")
        for i in nums:
            print("Your current bingo card:")
            player_1_card()
            print("Number called is", # )
            input("Press <enter> to call a number")
            if nums(#) in player_1:
                nums.remove(#)
```

I have placed hashes where I need some help with the code.

I am using Python 3.5.2.

Comment: Man, you have an unclear description of what you want and this `player_1_card()`... what is that?

Comment: @ outoftime Thanks  i had not noticed and i have placed and edit in with what the player_1_card does

Comment: @outoftime What i want to do is get the program to get the first element of   nums and then get the program to print it and if it is in the player_1 list then remove it

Comment: `nums = ['{0:02}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 100)]`

Comment: could you possibly explain to me what this does

Comment: This is [Format String Sytanx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) with [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Furthermore [RTFD](https://docs.python.org/3/)

Comment: where abouts would i put it

Comment: You have to find it out.

Comment: thank you for your hellp